# SharePoint 2010 web application migrate Server 2008 to server 2012 R2 Ajax Control toolkit error

Tags: 2010, migration, ajax-control-tookit

Previous Farm : SharePoint 2010,server 2008,SQL 2008

New Farm :SharePoint 2010,server 2012 R2,SQL 2014

Goal : migration web application to new server

Steps :

1. create backup whole farm full backup from the central admin
2. copy backup in new server
3. install SharePoint 2010 SP2 in new server
4. new web aplication crete in new server
5. Restore web application from old server backup

**Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to install that tool kit into the new farm. That is 3rd party toolkit which is not backed up using the sharepoint backup method.

Please install that and then test your web application.

I think Ajax control toolkit is a codeplex solution